# Hbase import ^A (CTRL A ) delimited file using importTsv

Tags: java, shell, hbase, mapper

I have a plain text file, rows are delimited by '\n' and columns are delimited by '^A',which is a nonprinting character. I need to load this file to HBase and I came across the tool importtsv which seems can do what I need.

I did some research and figured out so far:

```
hbase org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.ImportTsv \
-Dimporttsv.columns=col1,col2,col3 \
-Dimporttsv.skip.bad.lines=true \
'-Dimporttsv.separator=|' \
-Dmapred.job.name=job_name \
user_action_log \
/data2/result
```

However, I don't know how can I pass the control A into `'-Dimporttsv.separator=|'`, I took a look at the source code of this ImportTsv [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.cloudera.com/content/repositories/releases/com.cloudera.hbase/hbase/0.89.20100924-28/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/mapreduce/ImportTsv.java#ImportTsv.TsvParser.0separatorByte).

[image]

I am by no means Java savvy enough to figure this out and wondering if any of you who knows Java can help me pass the control A from the command line to the Java class?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

With `bash`, `ksh` and `zsh`, you can pass a Ctrl-A character using `$'\x01'`:

```
hbase org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.ImportTsv \
  -Dimporttsv.columns=col1,col2,col3 \
  -Dimporttsv.skip.bad.lines=true \
  -Dimporttsv.separator=$'\x01' \
  -Dmapred.job.name=job_name \
  user_action_log \
  /data2/result
```

For posix `sh`, you can instead use `$(printf "\x01")`.